# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a machine learning project and I want to make a neural network my purpose. Below is the code of my model, it is working fine with `Dense` layer but is is giving error with `LSTM` layer

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.LSTM(512, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='softmax'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(6)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="rmse",
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=4200)
```

Error message

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (4200, 25)
```

Comment: Input should be in the following format: `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. You can try expading dims: `np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)`

Comment: You can post this as answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before fitting the model I reshaped the training and testing dataset as directed by Frightera as

```
X_train=np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
X_test=np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=-1)
```